# Private RSS Feed

Tags: rss, plone

How can I force basic http authentication instead of cookie authentication for one url / browser view and not to switch complete site away from cookie thing.
We do not want to allow login parameters in url anymore.: 
/foren/RSS?__ac_name=meinloginname&__ac_password=meinpassword
So feed readers need basic http authentication to access the feed.

Comment: Yes that sounds good. So I need a challenger plugin putting before the other two challengers. This should handle RSS like basic challenger and ignore others to let them be handled by next challenger, cookie auth helper. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basic authentication is always supported; if a basic auth header is present the cookie-based login form redirect will not be shown.

Presumably you want to disable the redirect for the RSS feed instead, so when basic auth headers are not present a 401 auth-required response is sent instead of a redirect?

If so, then you'll need to provide PluggableAuthService plugin, implementing the  `IChallengePlugin` interface to intercept the `challenge()` call and make sure unathorized is raised *before* the `CookieAuthHelper` plugin can redirect.